# HTML5 Drag and Drop - Map

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I have to make a map of Europe with its countries
and then I need a few pics of products from those countries
After that I have to match the pic with the country with drag and drop 
if the product is dropped on the correct country it should send me to another page (with more info about the product)
if it's wrong it should display a message
anyone have an idea? I checked for some basic drag and drop stuff but since I'm new to html5 etc and webdesign in general it's really hard to make this from scratch
thanks!

EDIT: also only use HTML, CSS, JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with the [MapQuest JavaScript API](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/javascript). What I would start with is by [adding polygon overlays](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/documentation/sdk/javascript/v7.0/overlays#polygon) to the map for each country, the colour can be sett to completely transparent by setting the opacity for the overlay to `0.0`. From each overlay [add a `mouseup` event listener to each overlay](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/documentation/sdk/javascript/v7.0/events#overlay_events), this event listener can then be used to determine what it was you were dragging in the first place.

For the drag start functionality you can either do this yourself or you could use something like the [jQuery UI draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) support, you could then use the `dragstop` event from the draggable API in conjunction with `mouseup` on the overlay to perform your logic.

[Check out the basic map to get a map going](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/documentation/sdk/javascript/v7.0/basic-map).

Some code to start with

```
var countryCode;

// Adds an overlay and wires an event for mouseup.
function addMapOverlay(points, cc) {
    var poly = new MQA.PolygonOverlay();
    poly.setShapePoints(points);
    poly.color = "#ffffff";
    poly.colorAlpha=0.0;
    poly.fillColor = "#ffffff";
    poly.fillColorAlpha=0.0;
    poly.addListener(rectangle, 'mouseup', function(evt) {
        if (evt.eventName === "mouseup") {
            // Here you have the event firing for the mouse-up on the overlay.
            countryCode = cc;
        }
    });
}
```

For the drag-start.

```
$("#some-country-item").draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        countryCode = null;
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        if (countryCode === "what you expected") {
            // Released on correct country.
        } else {
            // Did not release on correct country.
        }
    }
});
```

You may need to test the event handling to ensure that the correct events are fired in the right order, or use the `mouseover` event on the overlay object.

The code samples are theoretical and should help you find the right direction to go.